# Will insects/rot from an untreated log in my garden spread to my house?

Tags: wood, insect, termite, rot, firewood

I have a large fresh log from a tree my neighbors cut down earlier this year in my yard. I got it to serve as a bench and grow mushrooms on, with the hope that it would eventually start decomposing and contribute to my garden ecosystem (with bugs that would attract woodpeckers, etc). I'm new to homeownership though, and I'm worried that having a rotting log in my yard ~15 feet from the home (it's a small yard) will spread things like termites or rot to the wood of my house, making it a very costly and destructive piece of lawn decor. Is what I'm doing a bad idea?

Comment: Yes it will attract thermites

Comment: @Ruskes -- yup, gotta watch out for those [thermites](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CWMATrOatRw).

Comment: Please dont post the [same](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/63088/is-it-bad-for-my-house-to-keep-a-decomposing-log-in-my-garden) question on multiple sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For termites what matters is how well you control the moisture around the house (rain run-off, year-round moist soil, drainage), whether wood from the house contacts the ground, and whether you live in an active termite area.

For other insects you should inspect all doorways and ensure the threshold is clean, dry and not close to soil. And treat and clean entry ways regularly.

Living near or in a forest often means living near decomposing logs, and so this is not uncommon. The close vicinity of your log does require careful observation. You might benefit from an insect barrier, e.g. with channels of diatomaceous earth and/or cedar & rock barriers.

https://homesteadandchill.com/diatomaceous-earth-garden-pest-control/

https://www.orkincanada.ca/pests/other/termites/